# JSON-LD Schema.org: Multiple video/image page

Tags: web, seo, schema.org, json-ld

I can't figure out how you would define a bunch of videos on the same page. i.e. a search page. Let's say you've a site that returns 50 different videos. Then how are you supposed to define this with `JSON-LD`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you have multiple items as value of a property, you could use an [array](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#sets-and-lists):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "video":
  [
    {
      "@type": "VideoObject"
    },
    {
      "@type": "VideoObject"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

If you have multiple items on the top-level (not as value of a property), you could use a [(named) graph](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#named-graphs) and an array:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@graph": 
  [
    {
       "@type": "VideoObject"
    },
    {
       "@type": "VideoObject"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

And you could of course use [multiple `script` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30730343/1591669):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "video": 
  {
    "@type": "VideoObject"
  }
}
</script>

<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "video": 
  {
    "@type": "VideoObject"
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: (Note that this is just example code, not tailored to your specific case. If you wonder *which* Schema.org types and properties you should use, this should be a separate question.)