# Multiple JSON-LD tag groups in one page

Tags: html, schema.org, json-ld

Can I use multiple JSON-LD groups (using Schema.org) in the same page?

If I can't, how to combine them together? I'm not so familiar with the syntax.

**Group 1:**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "3102 Highway 98",
    "addressRegion": "FL",
    "addressLocality": "Mexico Beach",
    "postalCode": "45252",
    "addressCountry": "US",
  },
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": "40.75",
    "longitude": "73.98"
  },
  "name": "Beachwalk Beachwear & Giftware",
  "telephone": "850-648-4200",
  "email": "admin@example.com",
  "faxNumber": "860-562-4250",

}
</script>
```

**Group 2:**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "url": "http://example.com",
    "name": "My Domain Title",
    "logo": "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/abc.jpg",
    "contactPoint": [
        {
            "@type": "ContactPoint",
            "telephone": "0192-39192130",
            "contactType": "customer service"
        },
        {
            "@type": "ContactPoint",
            "telephone": "0182-239120398",
            "contactType": "customer service"
        }
    ],
    "sameAs": [
        "http://facebook.com/myfbaccount",
        "http://twitter.com/mytwitteraccount"
    ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best JSON-LD practices: using multiple <script> elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723531/best-json-ld-practices-using-multiple-script-elements)

Comment: Related: [JSON-LD script elements (data blocks) MUST only contain valid JSON](https://github.com/w3c/json-ld-syntax/issues/96)

Answer (score 13):

You can either have multiple script blocks on your page or combine it in a single block. The easiest way to combine them into a single block is to use the `@graph` keyword as follows:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@graph": [
    { ... your first JSON-LD block ... },
    { ... your second JSON-LD block ... }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#h3_advanced-context-usage) the usage of several contexts is possible with a simple list of contexts:

```
[
  {
    "@context": "http://example.org/contexts/person.jsonld",
    "name": "Manu Sporny",
    "homepage": "http://manu.sporny.org/",
    "depiction": "http://twitter.com/account/profile_image/manusporny"
  },
  {
    "@context": "http://example.org/contexts/place.jsonld",
    "name": "The Empire State Building",
    "description": "The Empire State Building is a 102-story landmark in New York City.",
    "geo": {
      "latitude": "40.75",
      "longitude": "73.98"
    }
  }
]
```