# How many json LD can I put in a web page?

Tags: json-ld

as title, I need to insert two json LD in my pages.

The requirement is:
1) insert in all pages a json LD relating to "@type": "Organization"
2) insert in product pages a json LD relating to "@type": "car"

I read the documentation but I did'nt find an example with two json LD in page.
So my question is: can I put two json LD in the same page?

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best JSON-LD practices: using multiple <script> elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723531/best-json-ld-practices-using-multiple-script-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put multiple JSON-LD blocks into your page. Btw. you can use the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) to test your markup.