# Best practice for large site

Tags: json-ld

I am working on a large site and want to implement `JSON-LD`. The site has a large social media following and a lot of artist profiles and articles.

This is what I currently have, (the following code is from Google's guidelines)

**Front page**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "name": "Organization name",
  "url": "http://www.your-site.com",
  "sameAs": [
    "http://www.facebook.com/your-profile",
    "http://instagram.com/yourProfile",
    "http://www.linkedin.com/in/yourprofile",
    "http://plus.google.com/your_profile"
  ]
}
</script>
```

**Content pages**

```
<script type='application/ld+json'> 
{
 "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
 "@type": "WebSite",
 "name": "About us",
 "url": "http://www.your-site.com/about-us"
}
</script>
```

**Profile pages of each artist:**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https://google.com/article"
  },
  "headline": "Article headline",
  "image": [
    "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
   ],
  "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
  "dateModified": "2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Doe"
  },
   "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Google",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://google.com/logo.jpg"
    }
  },
  "description": "A most wonderful article"
}
</script>
```

Do I add one script tag per page or do I add all `JSON-LD` under one script tag? On the front page I have the "Organization" tag and show the social media links, do I add this on all pages?

Answer (score 1):

You [may have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30730343/1591669) multiple `script` JSON-LD data blocks on a page, but using one `script` element makes it easier to connect the structured data entities: you can nest entities instead of having to [reference their URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776122/1591669).

What to connect? Your `NewsArticle` can

- provide the `WebPage`¹ entity as value for the `mainEntityOfPage` property, and
- provide the `Organization` entity as value for the `publisher` property.

This is only one possibility. Another one: You could  provide the `WebPage` entity as top-level item and provide the `NewsArticle` entity as value for the `mainEntity` property.

If you have to duplicate data (for example, because the `Organization` is `author` and `publisher`, or because it’s the `publisher` of both, the `WebPage` and the `NewsArticle`), you can mix nesting and referencing. [Give each entity an `@id`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633) and wherever you provide this entity as value, also provide its `@id`.

---

¹ You are using `WebSite`, but you probably mean `WebPage`. Also note that the `@context` should be `http://schema.org`, not `http://www.schema.org`.

Comment: Thank you unor, it's a bit clearer now. I copied the code from Google, so not sure why the @context is wrong...