# Many JSON-LD script elements per page or a single one with nesting?

Tags: html, schema.org, json-ld

Let's say we have an ecommerce like Adidas. We have the basic JSON-LD structure for the `WebSsite`:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "url": "https://adidas.com/us",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "https://adidas.com/us/search?q={search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
```

We have the `Organization`:

```json
{
  '@context': 'http://schema.org',
  '@type': 'Organization',
  'name': 'Adidas',
  'description': 'Sport Shop',
  'email': 'adidas@adidas.us',
  'url': 'http://www.adidas.us',
  'logo': 'http://www.adidas.us/logo.svg'
}
```

The website is also a `Store`:

```json
 "@context":"http://schema.org",
 "@type":"Store",
 "url": 'http://www.adidas.us',
 "description": "Adidas Shop !",
 "name": "Adidas"
}
```

And we have also the classic `BreadcrumbList`:

```json
 "@context":"http://schema.org",
 "@type":"BreadcrumbList",
 "itemListElement":
  [  
    {  
       "@type":"ListItem",
       "position":1,
       "item":{  
          "@type":"Thing",
          "@id":"https://www.adidas.us",
          "name":"Adidas"
       }
    },
    {  
       "@type":"ListItem",
       "position":2,
       "item":{  
          "@type":"Thing",
          "@id":"https://www.adidas.us/shoes",
          "name":"Adidas shoes"
       }
    },
    {  
       "@type":"ListItem",
       "position":3,
       "item":{  
          "@type":"Thing",
          "@id":"https://www.adidas.us/shoes/Featured",
          "name":"Adidas featured shoes"
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

These 3 JSON-LD are common (more or less detailed of course), and sometimes I have found in a webpage 3 `script` elements with these JSON-LD, sometimes just 1, sometimes 2.

Should we try to nest them into one single `script` (if so, how !?), or is it better to keep them splitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important is that you connect the entities with suitable properties, [not how many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30730343/1591669) `script` elements you use.

If you have these three entities on a page, you [should convey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46524557/1591669) how they are related. What you probably want to convey: there is a web page that is part of that website, that is published by that organization, and that has that a breadcrumb list.

So what you are missing is an entity representing the web page (→ [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage)) and properties to connect all your entities (→ [`publisher`](http://schema.org/publisher), [`breadcrumb`](http://schema.org/breadcrumb), [`isPartOf`](http://schema.org/isPartOf)).

In how many `script` elements you specify these entities is up to you:

- One `script`, nesting all entites.
- One `script`, with multiple top-level objects (using `@graph` and `@id`).
- A `script` per entity (using `@id`).
- A combination of the above.

The first one is the most simple:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "isPartOf": {
    "@type": "WebSite"
  },
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization"
  },
  "breadcrumb": {
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList"
  }
}
```

[Give each relevant entity an `@id`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633), so you can [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776122/1591669) these entities on the same page (in the same `script` element or in other ones), or even on external pages.

I’m using it here to convey that the same `Organization` is the `publisher` of the `WebPage` as well as the `WebSite`:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "@id": "",
  "isPartOf": {
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "@id": "/#this-site",
    "publisher": {"@id": "/#this-org"}
  },
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "@id": "/#this-org"
  },
  "breadcrumb": {
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok this is awesome. thank you so much @unor. So hard to find detailed info about this. So following your last snippet how could we add 'Store' @type
I have seen passing an arr of types`"@type": ["Website", "Store"]`   Is this a good way to do it? 
Or we can add "Store" as a new key under `"Breadcrumb"` 
And Adidas Store is also a "ShoeStore"... `"@type": ["Website", "Store", "ShoeStore"]`?

As u can see, the confuse part to me is this nesting.
Webpage has also  a key specialty (One of the domain specialities to which this web page's content applies) 
`"specialty" : { @type: "Store" }`

Comment: @HéctorLeón: While you *could* add data to the `BreadcrumbList` structure, I wouldn’t do it (consumers might skip the whole item if they are not interested in breadcrumbs). -- There are various ways how `Store` could be connected -- it depends on your exact use case (to answer this, more details are needed; might warrant a new question; if only asking about which property to use, probably best at [webmasters.se]). -- By the way: If it’s a `ShoeStore`, you don’t have to specify `Store` in addition, because `ShoeStore` has `Store` as parent type.

Comment: And one more question, why the slash /   before the hashtag ? in the `"@id": "/#ID-HERE"`

Comment: Oh thanks, so am not forcing to specify parent, they just inherit his parent properties. Nice thanks again,  i will join to that community and post then a new question :)

Comment: @HéctorLeón: The goal is to specify a URI that represents the actual thing, not just a page where this thing is described; the `#` helps to disambiguate ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017139/1591669)). So for a website at `https://example.com/`, specifying `"@id": "/#this-org"` somewhere, the resulting URI would be: `https://example.com/#this-org`. Whenever you mention this organization in your structured data, you should specify this URI. Now, that’s just an example -- you can use whatever URI you want, of course (`/organization#this`, `/foobar552#organization` etc.).