# Where to place multiple JSON-LD objects in a webpage?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

## My webapge

I am building a [webpage](http://tlv.serverlessdays.org) for a conference. The page contains multiple objects like `speaker` ([Person](http://schema.org/Person)), or `session` ([Event](http://schema.org/Event)).

## My problem

I would like to add semantic data to the page, so that search engines and social networks can easily understand its content. I would like to both describe the page as a whole, and parts of it - like a single session

## My question

How do I mark up both the entire page and inner objects in a standard way?
Can I use multiple [JSON-LD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-LD) in the same page, or should I use JSON-LD for the page as a whole and other markups for inner objects?

## Clarification, following the comments

Thanks for pointing out the answer to [JSON-LD Schema.org: Multiple video/image page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505796/json-ld-schema-org-multiple-video-image-page). However, it I am not sure where should I put the different JSON-LD objects so that each of them refers to a specific part of the document. Should they be linked using div ids? Should the `<script>` be placed inside the relevant div?

Comment: I think your question could be a duplicate of these: [JSON-LD Schema.org: Multiple video/image page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30505796/1591669) and/or [How do you combine several JSON-LD markups?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48294593/1591669). The last example in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48295719/1591669) to the second question shows how you would ideally specify a `WebPage` object and provide nested objects for the related entities.

Comment: @unor Added a clarification

Answer (score 2):

You *can include multiple structured-data elements* on a page if you wish as per Google's guideline:

- https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies#multiple-elements-on-a-page

The best way to tell whether it can parse your expected JSON-LD objects and attributes is to use their `Structured Data Testing Tool`

- https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure where should I put the different JSON-LD objects so that each of them refers to a specific part of the document.

With JSON-LD, the structured data is not "coupled" to the HTML. (That would be possible with the syntaxes Microdata and RDFa, but even there, *after* extracting the structured data, it’s of no relevance anymore on which HTML elements it was specified.)

If you have a page about two persons, you would just provide one `WebPage` and two `Person` objects. To be able to make statements about these objects from other places, it’s a good practice to [give them URIs](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98578/17633), which can be specified [with `@id`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776122/1591669). For the `WebPage`, the URI would typically be the canonical URL of the page.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "@id": "",
  "about": [
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "@id": "#person-1"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "@id": "#person-2"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Theoretically, there could be a property which allows you to reference the HTML elements which describe the entity. Schema.org currently has properties like that in Pending, which are used for [`SpeakableSpecification` (Pending)](http://pending.schema.org/SpeakableSpecification): [`cssSelector` (Pending)](http://pending.schema.org/cssSelector) (using CSS selectors to reference the elements), [`xpath` (Pending)](http://pending.schema.org/xpath) (using XPath to reference the elements). But these can’t be used for other cases (as currently defined). So you would have to define your own property for this purpose.

> Should they be linked using div ids?

You could provide the `id` value in the object’s `url` property. It doesn’t "link" the HTML to the structured data, though. It just conveys: *You can find information about the entity described by this node object by following this URL.*

Often each entity has its own page, but it’s perfectly fine to describe multiple entities on the same page, of course.

Expanding the example from above:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "@id": "",
  "about": [
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "@id": "#person-1",
      "url": "#about-person-1"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Person",
      "@id": "#person-2",
      "url": "#about-person-2"
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

> Should the `<script>` be placed inside the relevant div?

For the structured data, it [makes no difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28688394/1591669) where in the HTML document the `script` elements are placed.

You could place all objects in one `script` element (like in the examples above), or you could use multiple `script` elements, but then you should reference their `@id` values so that you can still make use of properties like `about` (example in my answer linked above). It makes no difference semantically.