# Multiple @types together or in separate script tags?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm trying to wrap my head around this and I've read through several tutorials including schema.org documentation and Googles structured data guides and I can't find a clear answer on this. It's intuitive how to do this with microdata but not so much using JSON-LD. Let's say I have a website that is a local business and I offer products for sale. How would I combine both the LocalBusiness and Products into the same JSON-LD block of code? They are separate objects as far as my understanding.

Would the code look more like this...

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "name": "My Business"
}
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "My Proudct"
}
 </script>
```

or in separate `script` tags like this...

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "name": "My Business"
}
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "My Proudct"
}
 </script>
```

or something else altogether?

Comment: I think [this question might be duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48294593/1591669). At least I’d give almost the same answer here. You should try to implement the last way described in my answer (there are properties to connect `LocalBusiness` and `Product`, possibly with intermediate items, depending on your use case). -- Do you agree that it’s a duplicate? If not, please [edit] your question to make the difference between the questions clear :)

Comment: Yes, that is the answer I was looking for! thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you combine several JSON-LD markups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294593/how-do-you-combine-several-json-ld-markups)