# Multiple json scripts on homepage

Tags: json, seo, schema, schema.org

Is it fine if I apply multiple JSON scripts on homepage with the same schema.org type (trip) but different information within them?

We have few tourist trips with different destinations (itinerary) provided on our homepage. I would like to markup them in the best convenient way.

**There is already main script with unique hashtag id for describing business:**
`"@id" : "https://URL/#AutomotiveBusiness"`, 
**which states about what the homepage is and to which subject it belongs:**
`"@type" : "AutomotiveBusiness"`.

**For marking up trips I use the following separately placed script, for each trip:**

```
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"BusTrip",
    "image":"URL.jpg",
    "busName":"XYZ",
    "schema:provider": {
    "@type":
        "schema:Organization",
        "schema:name":"XYZ",
        "schema:url":"https://URL/"
    },
    "description":"XYZ",
    "url": "XYZ",
    "itinerary": {
        "@type":"City",
        "name":"City Name",
        "description":"XYZ",
        "url": "https://wikipedia.org/wiki/City Name"
    }
}
```

**Other questions:**

- Can I use main hashtag `@id` (the one which describes business) in order to markup provider?
  Let's say the code will look like this:

"schema:provider": {
    "@id":"https://URL/#AutomotiveBusiness",
    "@type":
    "schema:"AutomotiveBusiness",
    "schema:name":"XYZ",
    "schema:url":"https://URL/"
}

In this case, it will be better to use `"schema:AutomotiveBusiness"` for `@type` stating or "schema:organization"?

- Is it better to make arrays of markups (with trips) in one script or place them separately using multiple JSON scripts?

**Summing up:**
I am looking how can I place these trips well so it will be clearly assigned on the homepage to the business. I was thinking about going with stating same `@id` as for the main script about business within trips scripts...

Any ideas?

Comment: For the provider you can just include the id. That's enough for systems to connect it with the other information you have already provided on the page.

Comment: The other question is:
After setting for provider @id: "https://XYZ/#AutomotiveBusiness" for bustrip script on the same page at which we have main script for describing business, the tool for testing structured data does not show this main script. It is still in the <head> section, however, testing tool removed it.

Comment: SEO is off topic here. Please delete this and ask, instead, on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Regarding multiple script elements, I had asked this question in the past and got some pretty great answers: [Best JSON-LD practices: using multiple <script> elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723531/best-json-ld-practices-using-multiple-script-elements)

Summed up, multiple scripts is fine.

For your other question:

`AutomotiveBusiness` is a descendant of `Organization`, so if `AutomotiveBusiness` accurately describes the organization I think that would be good to use. Keep in mind [Schema.org](https://schema.org/AutomotiveBusiness) describes this as:

> Car repair, sales, or parts.

You could even get more specific and do [AutoRental](https://schema.org/AutoRental) if that makes more sense. I ran a basic example through the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) and it validated fine.

One other note I'd mention is if you have specific pages dedicated to these trips it might make more sense to put the JSON on those specific pages than the homepage.