# How to use JSON-LD when there are multiple hotel room entities on the same page?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I am working to develop JSON-LD scripts for one of my hotel client but stumbled upon the "Rooms" page in the website.

The [Google policies](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies) say:

> When you have multiple entity types on a page, we recommend you mark up all entities on that page to help Google algorithms better understand and index your content.

HTML tagging seems simple for this purpose, but how can we use JSON-LD to mark multiple rooms, their types, prices etc. when they are in single page?

I am using the `Product` type for the time being, since something like a "Hotel Room" type does not exists yet in Schema.org.

PS: Creating individual page for each room seems not a very good option to me.

EDIT:
I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505796/json-ld-schema-org-multiple-video-image-page), but that's specific to a webpage containing several videos and does not correctly addresses the case I've raised in this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON-LD Schema.org: Multiple video/image page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505796/json-ld-schema-org-multiple-video-image-page)

Answer (score 0):

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30506476/1591669) to the linked question describes three ways how multiple nodes can be specified in JSON-LD:

- if there is a suitable property: in an array as value of the property
- if there is no suitable property: as top-level items (either in `@graph` or in separate `script` elements)

If one page is for multiple rooms, you could use [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage) and provide an [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) as [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity), where each room is a list entry.

So in JSON-LD, [`itemListElement`](http://schema.org/itemListElement) would get an array as value (first example in my linked answer).

(Note that some time after you asked the question, Schema.org introduced the [`HotelRoom`](http://schema.org/HotelRoom) type. This can be used together with `Product`, as described on [Markup for Hotels](http://schema.org/docs/hotels.html).)