# JSON-LD - Does using the `location` property the correct way to markup multiple business locations?

Tags: html, json, schema.org, json-ld

I am tasked to optimized our clients website using structured data (JSON-LD) to be search engine friendly. Our client's business has multiple locations and **I am wondering if using the `location` property to structure the different business location is correct. Or should I just mark up each location separately?**

Here is a sample code of what I did (although validating this using the Google structured data testing tool results in **All good**, I'm wondering if I am using the `location` property correctly)

Also, I remove some of the properties to make the code small and replace the values with generic values:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Attorney",
"name" : "Example Injury Lawyer",
"url": "http://example.com/",
"logo": "http://example.com/assets/images/logo.png",
"location": [{
    "@type": "Attorney",
    "@id": "http://example.com/offices/city-injury-lawyer",
    "name": "Example Injury Lawyer",
    "url": "http://example.com/offices/city-injury-lawyer",
    "telephone": "+1-555-555-5555",
    "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "Street Address",
        "addressLocality": "City",
        "addressRegion": "Region",
        "postalCode": "12345",
        "addressCountry": "US"
    }
}, {
    "@type": "Attorney",
    "@id": "http://example.com/offices/another-city-injury-lawyer",
    "name": "Example Injury Lawyer",
    "url": "http://example.com/offices/another-city-injury-lawyer",
    "telephone": "+1-333-333-3333",
    "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "Street Address",
        "addressLocality": "City",
        "addressRegion": "Region",
        "postalCode": "54321",
        "addressCountry": "US"
    }
}]
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you wonder if it’s *syntactically* correct: yes, [using an array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30506476/1591669) (like you do for `location`) is the correct way to specify multiple nodes as value. Was this your question, or do you wonder if using Schema.org’s `location` (instead of some other property) is appropriate in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google does not yet use location information to drive it's data.

The structured data it does use is here: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/

So if you are looking to add maps and the like to your search results then you need to submit directly to Google Maps and/or Google My Business. It wasn't until I did this that the maps for the website I worked in started showing up in SERPS and knowledge graph.

Saying all that, I'm firmly of the belief that the more data you can give Google the better and I'd imagine they will use it at some point (as you'd think a website would be able to definitely define its location better than Google Maps for example which anyone can contribute to ). Whether or how they will accept multiple businesses if/when they do that remains to be seen. So I'd leave your JSON-LD data as you have it and just check the structured data testing tool periodically and keep an eye on above link - both of which are good things to do anyway.