# Is it possible to use different locations with Schema.org JobPosting?

Tags: location, schema.org, json-ld

I would like to use Schema.org for [`JobPosting`](https://schema.org/JobPosting), but the offer is for different cities ([`jobLocation`](http://schema.org/jobLocation)).

Can I mark 2-3 cities in this schema (with JSON-LD)? In that case, how?

Comment: I says, A (typically single) geographic location associated with the job position. So I guess I can define 2 or 3.

Answer (score 3):

According to Google: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-postings#definitions

> If the job has multiple locations, add multiple jobLocation properties
>   in an array. Google will choose the best location to display based on
>   the job seeker's query.

In json+ld it would look something like:

```
"jobLocation":[
    {
        "@type":"Place",
        "address":{
            "@type":"PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "555 Clancy St",
            "addressLocality":"Chicago",
            "addressRegion":"IL",
            "postalCode": "48201",
        }
    },
    {
        "@type":"Place",
        "address":{
            "@type":"PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "5 Main St",
            "addressLocality":"San Francisco",
            "addressRegion":"CA",
            "postalCode": "48212",
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

The [`jobLocation`](http://schema.org/jobLocation) property, like any property, can have multiple values. In JSON-LD, you have to use an array ([see example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30506476/1591669)).

But the question is what multiple values mean for this `jobLocation` property: do these represent all locations the person has to work in (*AND*), or do these represent alternatives and the person can choose (*OR*)?

Neither Schema.org nor JSON-LD offer a way for the author to disambiguate which one is meant.

In my opinion, multiple values should convey that the person has to work in all these places (*AND*). Why? Because otherwise there would be no way to convey this. If multiple locations would represent alternatives (*OR*), you can simply provide multiple `JobPosting` items (one for each location).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It was useful :D

Comment: @VKR: If it solved your question, note that you can accept this answer, which marks your question as answered. Accepting is possible by clicking at the checkmark (under my answer score, to the left).