# Multiple entries for email, phone, website, etc. in json-ld schema file

Tags: json, json-ld

Adding additional entries when a business has more than one phone number or emails, etc., how do you do this in a json-ld file?

It works fine in html, but when I add a second item in json and run it through the validator it return the last one entry, i.e., if I list three phone numbers it return last number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON-LD Schema.org: Multiple video/image page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505796/json-ld-schema-org-multiple-video-image-page)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see an answer to my question in that post.

Comment: The very first code snippet in my answer should answer it, no? It shows how you can provide multiple values for a property in JSON-LD.

Answer (score 5):

You have to define for example "Telephone" in this way :

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Example",
    "email": "mailto:example@example.com",
    "telephone": [
        "+123456789",
        "+987654321"
   ]
}
```

You check your Schema with [Google tool checker](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)

Answer (score 0):

It's note a valid code, you forget to add "," to the last line for phone tags :

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Example",
    "email": "mailto:example@example.com",
    "telephone": [
        "+123456789",
        "+987654321"
   ],
}
```