# Multiple organization in JSON-LD Schema.org markup

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I want to markup with Schema.org for my website with multiple organization. But, still I have only for single organization markup as follows:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
     "memberOf": {
   "@type": "",
  "name": "",
  "jobTitle": ""
  },
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "",
    "addressLocality": "",
    "addressRegion": "",
    "postalCode": "",
    "areaserved":"",
    "addressCountry":""
  },
   "email": "",
  "name": "",
  "telephone": ""
}
</script>
```

How to markup with multiple organization using the above format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON-LD Schema.org: Multiple video/image page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505796/json-ld-schema-org-multiple-video-image-page)

Answer (score 0):

## For not affiliated multiple organizations

The purpose is not clear. 
I assume, this is not a classified catalog.

Just list them. Add such script for every organization.

Someone here on stackoverflow suggested that multiple entities (like organizations) better be added with a separate script each.
Google does not mind finding multiple json-ld scripts on one page.

## For affiliated organizations or departments

Well, use this markup for every of your multiple organizations.
Only add `parentOrganization` property, linking to the parent global organization.

If you are listing departments, the only adjustment is to change "@type": "Organization" to "@type": "Department" for each child.
And link each child with `parentOrganization` per http://schema.org/parentOrganization