# JSON-LD for two entities in same page/view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json-ld

I want to update my web applications to use JSON-LD so that they get better on the search engines.

I read a lot on the JSON-LD website and the Google documentation about it but all of it deals with using a single entity.

What if on a single page -like my home page- I want to output TWO entities? For example the ORGANIZATION entity and the WEBSITE entity so that I can indicate the name of the site (and its alternate name) as well as the social site links that are also "same as" the web site?

When I tried appending them with a comma and tried it on the testing tool, it only "received" the first entity in the list

**UPDATE**
This is not a duplicate. For those who read carefully they will see that I am talking about TWO different entities being specified. The suggested duplicate is about a single entity with multiple (array) sub-attributes. That is not my case, mine is about multiple top level entities (Organization and Person for example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON-LD Schema.org: Multiple video/image page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505796/json-ld-schema-org-multiple-video-image-page)

Answer (score 0):

After a much deeper search with variations on the search words I managed to get my answer here: [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4LPnc72qFjBZEItZ05kWmNha1U/view)

So basically, if the entities/types are DIFFERENT as in my question (and unlike what the reviewer thought), then **you must use separate script tags for each JSON+LD entity/type**.