# Schema.org TVEpisode entries for multi-source playback page

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm expanding a static site with playable videos contextualized in a TV Series and I would like to know how to properly fill in the tags [`url`](http://schema.org/url) and [`datePublished`](http://schema.org/datePublished).

Currently, with only one embeddable source, the JSON-LD generated is:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "TVEpisode",
  "partOfTVSeries" : {
    "@type" : "TVSeries",
    "name" : "Name of the Show"
  },
  "keywords": "a,list,of,comma,separated,tags",

  "partOfSeason" : {
    "@type" : "TVSeason",
    "seasonNumber" : "1"
  },
  "episodeNumber" : "1",


  "image" : "absolute/path/to/video/image.jpg",

  "url" : "permalink",

  "review" : {
    "@type" : "Review",
    "author" : {
      "@type" : "Person",
      "name" : "Summary Author Name"
    },

"reviewBody" : "Summary"
  }
}
</script>
```

With only one embeddable source it was just a matter of using the template functions to retrieve the Permalink and the Date in which the video has been published.

But I don't know how to do it for multiple sources.

I tried to simply duplicate the whole block, simulating an iteration, changing the mentioned values but when testing with [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool), although no errors were reported, the second entry was ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSON-LD, if you have multiple values for a property, you have to [use an array as value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30506476/1591669) instead of repeating the property.

---

You could provide multiple [`VideoObject`](http://schema.org/VideoObject) items for the [`TVEpisode`](http://schema.org/TVEpisode), by using `TVEpisode`’s [`associatedMedia`](http://schema.org/associatedMedia)/[`encoding`](http://schema.org/encoding) property:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "TVEpisode",


  "associatedMedia": [
    {
      "@type": "VideoObject",
      "name": "Source 1"
    },
    {
      "@type": "VideoObject",
      "name": "Source 2"
    }
  ]


}
</script>
```

Now you can differentiate between the metadata for the TV episode and for its videos.

Comment: Using `associatedMedia` looks more organized to me. But if I suppress some fields common to all media, would I have any sort of suboptimal results for what matters? For example, all videos have the same `headline`, `thumbnailUrl`, `image` (varying with the seasons, of course) `height`, `width` and `keywords`. Since `TVEpisode` looks like "inherits" from `CreativeWork` through `Episode`, could I move these entries out of the `associatedMedia`?

Comment: @user5613506: Sure, if the data applies to the episode (and not just to a specific recording of it), you should specify it (at least) on the `TVEpisode` item. -- Depending on your use case, it can make sense to specify this data on the `VideoObject`s, too (so duplicating the data), for example, when a certain consumer ignores `TVEpisode` items because it only recognizes items of the `VideoObject` type. Unless you know of such a consumer, I wouldn’t go this way, though.

Comment: Well, after adjusting the data-structure to the `associatedMedia` format (Hugo syntax is a pain for this >.<) I tested and because `associatedMedia` requires a `VideoObject` and `VideoObject` has a few required fields (namely `name`, `description` and `thumbnailUrl`), even though they were already defined on `TVEpisode` I had to duplicate in there. It's not a big deal, I suppose, but in any event, thank you for the help. :)

Comment: @user5613506: In case you didn’t consider it yet: It might be easier for you to use RDFa or Microdata instead of JSON-LD, as you can add it directly to the HTML templates. --- Note that there are no required properties in Schema.org. Consumers like Google Search may require certain properties, but these are always only required for one of their search features -- if you don’t want the feature (or if you can’t get it, because you don’t have all the required data), there is no need to provide these properties.