# Using JSON-LD and Schema.org to mark up different events on same site

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I'm currently in the middle of an test, where I am asked to design a site that can give visitors an overview of upcoming events. The sites events has to be marked up with metadata using the Schema.org vocabulary.

I've made the page with both events on it, however when I try to validate the code on Google's test tool, it only shows one event as found:

[image: Result from googles tool]

I can't get it to recognize the second event, it just seems like Google skips the entire markup for that seperate event.

Is it possible for me to have both events marked up as well as some general markup of the site later on and if so what do I need to change so Google can recoqnize it as two events and not just one?

Attached is the entire markup in JSON-LD:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "MusicEvent",
    "name": "Nytårskoncert",
    "image": "http://www.kultunaut.dk/perl/images/billetten/W855H481_imageseventadvanced515158c14de20a020large.jpg",
    "startdate": "2017-01-10T20:00",
    "enddate": "2017-01-10T22:30",
    "performer": "Sønderjyllands Symfoniorkester",
    "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "Comwell Kolding Teater",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressCountry": "Denmark",
        "addresslocality": "Kolding",
        "postalcode": "6000",
        "streetaddress": "Skovbrynet 1"
      }
    },
    "description": "Til dette års nytårskoncert har vi engageret to vidunderlige og etablerede operasangere, sopranen Gitta Maria Sjöberg og tenor Eduardo Aladrén. Med disse to stemmer i front har vi plukket en buket af de skønneste arier og duetter fra operaens verden. Sønderjyllands Symfoniorkester dirigeret af Ola Rudner vil derudover bidrage med fejende wienervalse og festlige klassiske nytårstoner. En nytårskoncert, hvor vi byder 2018 velkommen med den skønneste nytårsmusik og sang."
  }, 
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "TheaterEvent",
    "name": "De Stuerene",
    "startDate": "2017-01-12T19:30",
    "endDate": "2017-01-12T22:00",
    "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "Mungo Park Kolding",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressCountry": "Danmark",
        "addressLocality": "Kolding",
        "postalCode": "6000",
        "streetAddress": "Fredericiagade 1"
      }
    },
    "description": "Historien om Dansk Folkeparti er vel den væsentligste i dansk politik i de sidste 20 år. Siden partiet blev stiftet i 1995 har Pia Kjærsgaards parti, mere end nogen, sat dagsordenen for hvad vi debatterer i vores land - og hvordan vi gør det. DE STUERENE er en tour-de-force gennem 20 år med Dansk Folkeparti. 20 år som måske har forandret den danske folkesjæl."
  }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a simple problem with your syntax. I added an array:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
  [{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "MusicEvent",
    "name": "Nytårskoncert",
    "image": "http://www.kultunaut.dk/perl/images/billetten/W855H481_imageseventadvanced515158c14de20a020large.jpg",
    "startdate": "2017-01-10T20:00",
    "enddate": "2017-01-10T22:30",
    "performer": "Sønderjyllands Symfoniorkester",
    "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "Comwell Kolding Teater",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressCountry": "Denmark",
        "addresslocality": "Kolding",
        "postalcode": "6000",
        "streetaddress": "Skovbrynet 1"
      }
    },
    "description": "Til dette års nytårskoncert har vi engageret to vidunderlige og etablerede operasangere, sopranen Gitta Maria Sjöberg og tenor Eduardo Aladrén. Med disse to stemmer i front har vi plukket en buket af de skønneste arier og duetter fra operaens verden. Sønderjyllands Symfoniorkester dirigeret af Ola Rudner vil derudover bidrage med fejende wienervalse og festlige klassiske nytårstoner. En nytårskoncert, hvor vi byder 2018 velkommen med den skønneste nytårsmusik og sang."
  }, 
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "TheaterEvent",
    "name": "De Stuerene",
    "startDate": "2017-01-12T19:30",
    "endDate": "2017-01-12T22:00",
    "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "Mungo Park Kolding",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressCountry": "Danmark",
        "addressLocality": "Kolding",
        "postalCode": "6000",
        "streetAddress": "Fredericiagade 1"
      }
    },
    "description": "Historien om Dansk Folkeparti er vel den væsentligste i dansk politik i de sidste 20 år. Siden partiet blev stiftet i 1995 har Pia Kjærsgaards parti, mere end nogen, sat dagsordenen for hvad vi debatterer i vores land - og hvordan vi gør det. DE STUERENE er en tour-de-force gennem 20 år med Dansk Folkeparti. 20 år som måske har forandret den danske folkesjæl."
  }
]
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed the issue. If i also need to mark up the site it self in the @type webpage, would i need a new script, a new array or just continue in a new set of {} after the event descriptions ?

Comment: @Frederik: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30506476/1591669). Ideally you would combine the various entities with suitable properties (e.g., `WebPage` `mainEntity` `Event`). If not possible, you have to provide top-level items. These can be specified either with an array (like Subtlebot’s answer shows) or with multiple `script` elements.