# How to solve the JSON-LD error "Duplicate key found"?

Tags: json, schema.org, json-ld

My Schema.org having this code for office hours and that gives me error when I test the URL using https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

How I can remove this error:

> JSON-LD    Duplicate key found.

I know where is the problem: `opens`, `closes`, `daysOfWeek`, these items are repeated.

I found [this solution](https://nateonawalk.com/how-to-fix-the-duplicate-key-found-structured-data-error/), but my problem having different scenario than this.

Please let me know the possible solution, so that I can change the data accordingly.

JSON-LD includes code:

```json
"openingHoursSpecification": {
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "openingHoursSpecification",
"opens" : "11:20 am ",
"closes": " 7:30 pm",
"dayOfWeek": {
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "dayOfWeek",
"name": "Mon"
},
"opens" : "10:20 am ",
"closes": " 7:30 pm",
"dayOfWeek": {
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "dayOfWeek",
"name": "Tue-Wed"
},
"opens" : "9:00 am ",
"closes": " 10:00 pm",
"dayOfWeek": {
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "dayOfWeek",
"name": "Thu"
},
"opens" : "11:00 am ",
"closes": " 4:00 pm",
"dayOfWeek": {
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "dayOfWeek",
"name": "Fri"
},
"opens" : "6:00 am ",
"closes": " 6:00 pm",
"dayOfWeek": {
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "dayOfWeek",
"name": "Sat"
},
"opens" : "10:00 am ",
"closes": " 11:40 pm",
"dayOfWeek": {
"@context" : "http://schema.org",
"@type" : "dayOfWeek",
"name": "Sun"
}},
```

Comment: Note that Schema.org terms are case-sensitive. The type has to be [`OpeningHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification), the property has to be [`openingHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/openingHoursSpecification). And it’s [`DayOfWeek`](http://schema.org/DayOfWeek) (not `dayOfWeek` nor `daysOfWeek`). And you don’t need to repeat the `@context` if you can specify it once at the top (assuming that you don’t use other vocabularies in addition).

Comment: Thank you for this information. Still wants to ask, why structure data testing tool not gives me error about that?

Comment: My another question is: Will it make any difference Mon and Monday, Sat and Saturday, etc?

Comment: Ah, I missed this when posting my previous comment: It’s not intended to use `dayOfWeek` like that. You should specify it like that: `"dayOfWeek": {"@id": "http://schema.org/Monday"}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you found applies to your case, too. If a property has multiple values, you need to [use an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30506476/1591669):

```json
"openingHoursSpecification": [
  {
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification"
  },
  {
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification"
  },
  {
    "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification"
  }
],
```

Comment: My error has been removed by Appling above solution, my another question is: Will it make any difference Mon and Monday, Sat and Saturday, etc?